# How to bind DataTable to Datagrid?

Tags: wpf

I have a problem binding a DataTable to a Gridview. I have already searched for solutions but just can't get rid of the error. The bindwing works fine when using WindowsForms, so the DataTable is correct. I just can't bind it to a WPF Gridview.

**XAML:**

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1"  ItemsSource="{Binding phnDirectory}"
```

**C#**

```
DataTable phnDirectory = obj.Getphone_directory();
listView1.ItemsSource = phnDirectory;
```

But it says "can not convert datatable to Collection.IEnumerables"

so what is the solution?
thanks in advance

Comment: please provide more code, your .xaml and .cs parts

Comment: XAML.... <ListView x:Name="listView"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="214" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="416.5" Margin="33,78,0,0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
               
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

Comment: C#           private void formload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

        {
            DataTable phnDirectory = obj.Getphone_directory();
            listView.ItemsSource = phnDirectory.DefaultView;
        }

Comment: The code in your question looks incomplete and differs from the one you gave in comments... Especially in the XAML part. Which one is correct? It is hard to try to help if the problem is unclear...

Comment: New one is correct

Answer (score 1):

Use this `listView1.ItemsSource = phnDirectory.DefaultView`

Comment: Correct answer but could use a few lines explaining why

Answer (score 0):

**XAML:**

```
<ListView Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

**C#**

```
DataTable phnDirectory = obj.Getphone_directory();
listView1.DataContext = phnDirectory.DefaultView;
```

Comment: it is DataGridView not DataGrid...it gives error with itemSource="{Binding}"

Answer (score 0):

A DataTable doesn't enumerate.

This is because what do you want to enumerate ? Columns, Rows, Constraints, Properties? you either need to tell it which you want to enumerate or link to the DataView via DefaultView 
e.g.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1"  ItemsSource="{Binding phnDirectory.DefaultView }"
```

or

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1"  ItemsSource="{Binding phnDirectory.Columns}"
```

in windows forms a datagrid is locked into showing Tables, a WPF GridView is merely a formatting note that says you want to view the data in a grid style there is no conversion on data

Comment: thnks ...sir but when i start debugger with all this....my datatable shows five columns ...and list view shows four columns in this way                             system.Data.DataRowView                                                                            system.Data.DataRowView                                                                             system.Data.DataRowView                                                                           system.Data.DataRowView

Comment: You need to configure how you display your data, if you just want a grid try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752213(v=vs.110).aspx or you can set a DataTemplate up to do something better